# Return value from Angular Service

Tags: angularjs, factory

Hi I do not understand why always I get empty array from this service when is invoked by my controller

```
angular
.module('dimecuba.services', [])
.factory('Contacts', function($cordovaContacts, $ionicPlatform) {

    var contactsFound = [];

    var contacts = {
        all:function(){
            var options = {};
            options.multiple = true;
            options.filter = "";
            //options.fields = ['displayName'];
            options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
                $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(
                    function(allContacts){
                        angular.forEach(allContacts, function(contact, key) {
                            contactsFound.push(contact);
                        });
                        console.log("Contacts Found:" + JSON.stringify(contactsFound));
                        return contactsFound;
                    }, 
                    function(contactError){
                        console.log('Error');
                    }
                );
            });
        }
    }; //end contacts
    console.log("Contacts:"+JSON.stringify(contacts));
    return contacts;
});
```

Comment: show what `$cordovaContacts` and `$ionicPlatform` contain. Are you injecting those services?

Comment: The objective is return contactsFound... how I can fix this code to return contacstFound

Comment: It seems that you are returning `contacts` instead of `contactsFound`. Declare `contactsFound` inside `contacts` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Use `return` to **chain** promises. A `return` statement needs to be included at each level of nesting.

```
app.factory('Contacts', function($cordovaContacts, $ionicPlatform) {

    var contacts = {
        all:function(){
            var options = {};
            options.multiple = true;
            options.filter = "";
            options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
            //return promise
            return $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function() {
                //return promise to chain
                return $cordovaContacts.find(options)
            }).then(function(allContacts){
                var contactsFound = [];
                angular.forEach(allContacts, function(contact, key) {
                    contactsFound.push(contact);
                });
                //return to chain data
                return contactsFound;
            }).catch(function(contactError){
                console.log('Error');
                //throw to chain error
                throw contactError;
            });
        }
    }; //end contacts

    return contacts;
});
```

In the controller, use the promise returned.

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,Contacts) {

    var contactsPromise = Contacts.all();

    contactsPromise.then( function(contactsFound) {
         $scope.contactsFound = contactsFound;
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be more elegant to reduce the level of nesting using `...ready().then (function() { return $cordovaContacts.find(options); }).then(...)`